# Coq: Functions for finding the lightest weight edge. Error msg

Tags: coq

I am trying to define a function that can find the lightest weight edges. Below is my code:

```
From LF Require Export Lists.
From LF Require Export Basics.
Require Import Program.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition vertics := list(nat).
Definition edges := list(nat*nat*nat).
Definition Graph := (vertics , edges).

Definition myEdges : edges := [(1,2,2);(1,3,2);(2,3,4)].

(*takes in a list of edges from the graph and returns the edge with the smallest weight.*)
Fixpoint minEdge (l: edges)(m: nat*nat*nat): nat*nat*nat :=
match l with
  | nil => m
  | cons h t => match h, m with
                | (a,b,w), (a2,b2,m) => if (leb w m) 
                 then (minEdge t (a,b,w))
                 else (minEdge t (a2,b2,m))
                end
  end.

Example minEdge_test : minEdge myEdges = (1,2,2).
```

(1,2,2) is (node1,node2,edge weight);
what I was thinking was the example test will prove my minEdge function will output -> (1,2,2).
While it gives me error msg like this:

```
The term "(1, 2, 2)" has type "(nat * nat * nat)%type" while it is expected to have type
 "nat * nat * nat -> nat * nat * nat".
```

Not sure where I made the mistake. And how can I fix this?? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just didn't pass the `m` parameter to your `minEdge` function.

You see this error because coq applies function to its arguments one-by-one.
So, if you have a function `f : A -> B -> C` then applying `f` to arument `a` of type `A` (`a:A`) will give you `f a : B -> C`. So, you can think about `f a` as about a new function from `B` to `C`.

In your situation you have `minEdge : edges -> nat*nat*nat -> nat*nat*nat`. And after applying `minEdge` to argument `myEdges` of type `edges` you receive `minEdge myEdges : nat*nat*nat -> nat*nat*nat`

Hope, that helps.